# Why does android studio want CalendarContract.Calendars instead of Calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to read and write to the calendar using my App. So I'm using the code from the [android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html):

I've copied this:

```
// Run query
Cursor cur = null;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;   
String selection = "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND (" 
                    + Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
                    + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"sampleuser@gmail.com", "com.google",
    "sampleuser@gmail.com"}; 
// Submit the query and get a Cursor object back. 
cur = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

However I get the error can not resolve symbol Calendars. The solution android studio offers is to change `Calendars` to `CalendarContract.Calendars`.

I'm just curious what the difference is? And possibly why the developer guide contains a flaw?

Comment: It doesn't contain a flaw. It just does not show the `import` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference is the `import` statement.

```
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
// Use Calendars
Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME


import android.provider.CalendarContract;
// Use CalendarContract.Calendars 
CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME
```

Comment: ah ok thanks, For some reason android studio wouldn't offer me the option of adding the import automatically